# Jenkins pipeline not getting webhook from bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a pipeline job to trigger on a push from my bitbucket account.
I already did this once using a freestyle job with no issue.

but I cannot get the pipeline to trigger from the webhook
I see multiple similar questions but they are all outdated and none of the solutions seem to apply.

I see the webhook in the Jenkins log
[image]

when I check the bitbucket pull request webhook log it is empty.
I tried the trick of running the build the very first time with no success

I also tried with and without the pollSCM option on - but from the help txt it seems on is the correct settings with no schedule defined!
[image]

I have no Idea where to go from here ?

Comment: Note I also Tried with the "trigger also if it tag is a push" option with no success